# Restrict Magento incrementing numeric at the end of the URL after re-indexing

Tags: php, mysql, magento, magento-1.7

I have Multi website,Multi store Magento with many of the products with duplicate url_key's. For duplicate url_key every re-indexing operations Magento unnecessarily keeps adding new url rewrite data by incrementing numeric at the end of the url and defines these new url rewrite rule of type 'custom'. My core_url_rewrite table in mysql is already grown beyond 2GB in one month only then imagine what could be table size after one year. 
I need to restrict Magento incrementing numeric at the end of the URL somehow programmatically. I went through this discussion http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/416476/ but *markf* with few others do not find *snowcountry*'s fix stable. Can you help me here with best solution? I will welcome entirely different approach as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes such thing happen if you have duplicate url's. Best way is never have duplicate URL's in your system. Duplicates URL's can be given a proper suffix to make it unique. Once you have no URL's remaining in your system you can truncate core_url_rewrite table and re-index Catalog URL Rewrites.

But in your case you can not afford to loose any Old Url then just correct you duplicate url's that you dont have any duplicate url's then reindex and everything will start working fine witout any numeric at the end. In this way neither you lost any old url they are still there pointing to new url's nor in further reindexing new url will be generated.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined any of the URL rewrites manually.

Then truncate all flat catalog category and product tables.
follw this by truncating core_url_rewrite table.

Then do reindexAll.

At this will reduce your core url number of rows.

Comment: Firstly, I can't afford to loose any of my previous url's. Secondly, In this way problem is still there and i will need to keep truncating my table every month.
Satish, As incrementing numeric at the end of the url after every URl re-indexing operation is a kind of Magento Bug. I wish we could solve this issue. app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Url.php is responsible file. I tried but couldn't do it.

Comment: Well My suggestion was till you get a solution this can be a way out.